# 15 inch MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave woke up with blue screen from sleep

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

So recently I came home after a few hours to my MacBook Pro (which was plugged in the whole day) and saw this:

[image: Screen of MacBook Pro]

What exactly would cause this?

More information on my system:

- Hardware: 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB, Radeon Pro 555X
- Software: I have Xcode installed, and the apps running in the background were Settings, Spotify, Atom (the text editor, with a fair number of plugins), and Chrome.

Update: Under Wilfred's suggestion, I ran a diagnostic. Nothing was picked up; it appears there are no issues according to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that pattern looks like uninitialized video memory. That kind of thing happens when the machine comes out of sleep incorrectly or if there is a GPU memory pin that is coming loose. I say that because it’s a regular pattern.

Regardless, if it’s under warranty, be sure that Apple has noted that you reported a problem.

Better safe than sorry.

Comment: I do have a warranty still, fortunately – and thank you so much for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest booting into diagnostic mode (search here or Google for instructions based on your particular Mac). Either it’s a fluke or your GPU is soon to die.

Comment: Just did, diagnostic said there were no issues

Comment: I did actually game a bit before I went away for a few hours; and I should note that I've only had issues when I leave my lid not closed (if that even matters?). Statistically speaking, I've only had issues when my laptop is left asleep for a long period of time with its lid not closed – I leave my laptop asleep periodically without shutting down for days with lid closed at night.

Answer (score 0):

It may be just a freak occurrence. If it happens again, you should bring it to an Apple store. Is it under warranty? If it is, be sure to get it checked out and have the issue on file before the warranty expires.