# Mac completely freezes when waking up from sleep

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, sleep-wake

When I wake my MacBook Pro 15 inch up from a long period of time (2-5 hours) of sleep, my Mac shows a black screen (there is clearly some backlighting, so its on, just showing only black), and my Touchbar is on. However, it responds to absolutely no input: the trackpad, keyboard all have no effect. The Touchbar and the screen are both completely frozen.

A restart does seem to put everything back to normal, however. I should also add that in the events that my Mac had these sleep issues, the case was open. Whenever I shut my MacBook, physically, and leave the lid down, I notice no issues whatsoever. I've left my mac on sleep with the lid down for hours at end (traveling, or when I'm asleep) with zero issues whatsoever. Statistically speaking, I only experience issues when the lid is left up the and the Mac falls asleep.

I should note that I've already asked a similar question before, where my screen was instead showing a repetitive pattern, rather than a black screen. The link: [15 inch MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave woke up with blue screen from sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362344/15-inch-macbook-pro-running-macos-mojave-woke-up-with-blue-screen-from-sleep)

As of that previous question, I have run a diagnostic with no issues found.

I don't know if the problem is hibernation or anything like that, but here is the relevant info:

```
❯ pmset -g                                                                 
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 proximitywake        1
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 sleep                1
 hibernatemode        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 tcpkeepalive         1
 highstandbythreshold 50
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

```
❯ pmset -g assertions
2019-06-15 23:03:12 -0700
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 354(useractivityd): [0x0000042d00018358] 00:00:01 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "BTLEAdvertisement"
    Timeout will fire in 58 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 352(sharingd): [0x000003c70001834e] 00:01:43 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Handoff"
   pid 100(hidd): [0x0000002900098145] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4294968616.3"
    Timeout will fire in 600 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
Kernel Assertions: 0x104=USB,MAGICWAKE
   id=504  level=255 0x4=USB mod=12/31/69, 4:00 PM description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14300000 owner=USB Receiver
   id=505  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE mod=6/15/19, 10:56 PM description=en0 owner=en0
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

*More information on my system:*

- Hardware: 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB, Radeon Pro 555X
- Software: I have Xcode installed, and the apps running in the background were  Spotify and iTerm.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with Macs, but it's usually easy to fix. You probably just need to reset your System Management Controller (SMC), which controls things like how your computer sleeps/wakes and responds to opening the lid from sleep, etc.
If this does not work, you could go a step further and reset your Nonvolatile Random- Access Memory (NVRAM) and/or your Parameter Ram (PRAM). These two things store small pieces of memory related to your system settings. The SMC, NVRAM, and PRAM all sometimes contain errors, or simply bug out, which just requires a quick resetting of their stored information. Sometimes the steps for resetting each differs depending on your model Mac, so I suggest reading through Apple's Official docs on their steps here:
[How to reset your Mac's SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)
and
[How to reset your Mac's NVRAM or PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

I hope this helps.